# how to access $route in js file using VueJS

Tags: vue.js

/* breadCrumb.js */

I wanted to create new file from where we can extract the detail in vuejs file

```
export const user = [{title: 'User List', link: `/${this.$route.param.menuid/user}`}, {title: 'Create User'}]
```

in js file $route will not reachable what will be good process to handle this

/* User.vue */

```
import {user} from '@/system/breadCrumb';

data(){
  return {
    breadCrumb : user
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using vue 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using vuejs 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `user` as a function and pass the  `menuid` as parameter, then define `breadCrumb` as computed that returns the `user` function with `this.$route.params.menuid` as argument :

```js
const user = menuid => [{ title: 'User List', link: `/${menuid}/user` }]
```

then:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    breadCrumb() {
      return user(this.$route.params.menuid)
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I have one question if I have to multiple service and in all service menuid has to send as parameter how can I make it with single object

Comment: const user = menuid => [{ title: 'User List', link: `/${menuid}/user` }]
const finance = menuid => [{ title: 'finance List', link: `/${menuid}/finance` }]
const account = menuid => [{ title: 'account List', link: `/${menuid}/account ` }]

Comment: The above make me 3 function can we make it one function and call it in computed breadcrumb function ?

Comment: create one function `const user = (title,menuid,param) => [{ title:title, link: `/${menuid}/${param}` }]` then create three computed properties